# Python for loop coding

Tags: for-loop

I am new newbie in Python,

One questions have here for the following python code:

`outputs = []
num_wrong = len([output[4] for output in outputs if output[4] == 'No'])`

1. What does `for output in outputs if output[4] == 'No'` doing?
2. What's the purpose of putting `output[4]` in front of  `for output in outputs if output[4] == 'No'`?

Comment: It's called a list comprehension. It creates a list of 'no' and then counts the length.

Comment: I'm too scared to answer this because I know it's going to get downvoted.

Comment: thank you for the hint and keyword "list comprehension" so I could google and learn by myself.